# Windows 7 crashes when transferring data from one drive to another

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, ssd, data-transfer

This problem has hounded me for a long time, well over a year.

When I am transferring data (usually large amounts) from one drive to another, the computer crashes and I either get a blue screen or it just reboots.

Originally I thought it was a faulty hard drive so I replaced that but the problem persisted. I have run smart drive diagnostics on all of my hard drives and no problems have been picked up.

I then replaced all of my RAM assuming it must be that. The problem continued.

I then replaced the video card. Same problem.

I then upgraded to windows 10 and the problem became more acute so I rolled back to windows 7.

The SSD has the latest firmware, graphics card the latest drivers.

I'm now thinking it's one of two problems:

Either my SSD drive which contains the operating system or the motherboard?

Has anyone got any ideas of how to specifically diagnose this problem or ways to resolve it? Would a clean installation help?

PC: Windows 7 SP1, AMD Phenom II X4 965, 16Gb RAM, AMD Radeon (TM) R9 200 Series,Asus motherboard M4A87TD/USB3

It is no longer saving the dumps. I have made the recommended changes and rebooted. This is the latest one available. The error is still the same.

```
==================================================
Dump File         : 010316-35303-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 03/01/2016 22:54:00
Bug Check String  : KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001e
Parameter 1       : ffffffff`c0000005
Parameter 2       : fffff880`06d90430
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : NETIO.SYS
Caused By Address : NETIO.SYS+7e6a
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+74200
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\010316-35303-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 4
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 275,536
Dump File Time    : 03/01/2016 22:55:44
==================================================
```

File shared:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4vdd4ItUiFCMHJsRFBoMHhhajQ&usp=sharing

Comment: What are the full BSOD error messages? [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) should provide this information. Please [edit] your question to include this.

Comment: [What information appears in event logs? (Event Viewer)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: bluescreenview is crap. Share the file C:\Windows\Minidump\010316-35303-01.dmp, so that we can debug it

Comment: are you using a LAN or WLAN adapter?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm using LAN

Comment: Did you verify your using the current driver with specific support for Windows 10

Comment: remove COMODO and look what happens

Comment: have you removed Comodo? Is the issue now fixed or not?

Answer (score 0):

The crash shows that a driver inspect.sys, which is part of COMODO (Firewall/AV):

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED (1e)
This is a very common bugcheck.  Usually the exception address pinpoints
the driver/function that caused the problem.  Always note this address
as well as the link date of the driver/image that contains this address.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffffffc0000005, The exception code that was not handled
Arg2: fffff88006d90430, The address that the exception occurred at
Arg3: 0000000000000000, Parameter 0 of the exception
Arg4: 0000000000000000, Parameter 1 of the exception

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for inspect.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for inspect.sys

DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  7601.19018.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.150928-1507

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  System manufacturer

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  System Product Name

SYSTEM_SKU:  To Be Filled By O.E.M.

SYSTEM_VERSION:  System Version

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  0601   

BIOS_DATE:  04/02/2010

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  ASUSTeK Computer INC.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  M4A87TD/USB3

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  Rev 1.xx

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  openvpn.exe

00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt!KipFatalFilter
02 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
03 nt!_C_specific_handler
04 nt!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
05 nt!RtlDispatchException
06 nt!KiDispatchException
07 nt!KiExceptionDispatch
08 nt!KiGeneralProtectionFault
09 afd!memmove
0a afd!AfdReceiveDatagramEventCommonHandler
0b afd!AfdReceiveDatagramEventHandler
0c tdx!TdxEventReceiveMessagesTransportAddress
0d tcpip!UdpDeliverDatagrams
0e tcpip!UdpReceiveDatagrams
0f tcpip!IppDeliverListToProtocol
10 tcpip!IppProcessDeliverList
11 tcpip!IppReceiveHeaderBatch
12 tcpip!IpFlcReceivePackets
13 tcpip!FlpReceiveNonPreValidatedNetBufferListChain
14 tcpip! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
15 nt!KeExpandKernelStackAndCalloutEx
16 tcpip!FlReceiveNetBufferListChain
17 ndis!ndisMIndicateNetBufferListsToOpen
18 ndis!ndisMDispatchReceiveNetBufferLists
19 ndis!ndisMTopReceiveNetBufferLists
1a ndis!ndisFilterIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists
1b ndis!NdisFIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists
1c inspect
1d 0x0
1e 0x0
1f 0x0

    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\inspect.sys
    Image name: inspect.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Wed Aug 05 01:20:30 2015
```

The driver version is from August 2015, so look if there is a program update for COMODO. if not, remove the tool completely and look if the issues are gone.